# How to connect json file to nodejs for sorting

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

I never use before json with nodejs and ejs so pardon my lack of knowledge. I am able to generate a list of items from the json but when I press the drop down for sorting, it is not showing any output other than default sorting by id based on the ejs below. Did I connect the json wrongly?

nodejs

```
router.get('/product', (req,res) =>{
    fs.readFile('items.json', function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).end()
            } else {
                res.render('product.ejs', {
                    user: req.user,
                    stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
                    items: JSON.parse(data)
                })
            }
    })
})
```

ejs

```
<select id="sortMed" onChange="getSelectValue()">
                <option onClick="defaultSorting()">Default Sorting</option>
                <option onClick="sortingbyPrice()">Sorting by price</option>
                <option onClick="sortingbyAlphabet()">Sorting by alphabet</option>
            </select> 

   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="shop-items" id="output">
                    <% items.medicine.forEach(function(item){ %>
                        <div class="shop-item" data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
                            <span class="shop-item-title"><%= item.name %></span>
                            <img class="shop-item-image" src="../assets/img/<%= item.imgName %>">
                            <div class="shop-item-details">
                                <span class="shop-item-price">$<%= item.price / 100 %></span>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% }) %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
function sortingbyPrice(){
        console.log("Sorting price")
        const itemsJson = JSON.parse(data)
        $.getJSON('items.json', function(data) {
            return sorted = items.medicine.sort((medA, medB) => medA.price - medB.price);
        });
    }
```

items.json

```
{
    "medicine": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bioderma",
        "price": 5000,
        "imgName": "product_01.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Chanca Piedra",
        "price": 2300,
        "imgName": "product_02.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Umcka",
        "price": 4000,
        "imgName": "product_03.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "CetylPure",
        "price": 8700,
        "imgName": "product_04.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "CLACORE",
        "price": 5600,
        "imgName": "product_05.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "POO-POURRI",
        "price": 6800,
        "imgName": "product_06.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Ibuprofen",
        "price": 6800,
        "imgName": "product_07.png"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: How are you reading the JSON file in a sortingbyPrice()?

Comment: The problem is more like I am able to show the list from json in ejs based on learning from a tutorial but I don't know how to connect the json file to the ejs for sorting. I don't think is reading it though through testing console.log

Comment: The return inside $.getJSON doesn't do anything good.  In there you need to populate your component with new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the sorting like this:

```js
const mockJsonData = {
    "medicine": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bioderma",
        "price": 5000,
        "imgName": "product_01.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Chanca Piedra",
        "price": 2300,
        "imgName": "product_02.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Umcka",
        "price": 4000,
        "imgName": "product_03.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "CetylPure",
        "price": 8700,
        "imgName": "product_04.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "CLACORE",
        "price": 5600,
        "imgName": "product_05.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "POO-POURRI",
        "price": 6800,
        "imgName": "product_06.png"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Ibuprofen",
        "price": 6800,
        "imgName": "product_07.png"
      }
    ]
  }
  
   const sortByPrice = () => {
      mockJsonData.medicine.sort((a, b) =>  a.price - b.price);
 }
sortByPrice();
console.log(mockJsonData.medicine);
```

Now, you have got the sorted medicine list, re-render the ejs template with this updated value.

```
res.render('product.ejs', {
                    user: req.user,
                    stripePublicKey: stripePublicKey,
                    items: sortingbyPrice(data) // data from reading JSON file
                });

// you sorting function be like


function sortingbyPrice(data){
        return itemsJson.medicine.sort((a, b) =>  a.price - b.price);
}
```

Also, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664209/update-ejs-variables-on-ajax-request).

Comment: if I have different type of sorting, do I put items: JSON.parse(data)?

Comment: It is not necessary, JSON.parse converts the stringify objects to JSON if they are valid one. If you have sorting by alphabet you can the other method. If this answer helps you, you can upvote it.

Comment: It shows correctly in the console log but it doesn't really shows the change in ejs after I click the showdown. But thank you for teaching me about the sorting!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite got how is the structure of the Json you have when you run the sorting.

In anycase, I've created this fiddle, so you can check a proper sorting inside an array of jsons, similar to what I expect you are getting in the node backend:

https://jsfiddle.net/9gpzwhs0/

```
console.log("Sorting price")
const itemsJson = [{
  medicine: {

    price: 2
  }
},
{
  medicine: {
    price: 1
  }
}
] 
console.log(itemsJson.sort((medA, medB) => medA.medicine.price 
- medB.medicine.price));
```

In the sorting, I've see that you are doing intems.medicine.sort, while you should do items.sort and inside the sorting function, return the medA.medicine.price

Comment: is it better if i just paste the json in the ejs and sort or which method is recommended when it comes to using json for sorting?

Comment: This sort method is pretty ok. It will not be a huge overhead and you can rely on it. Just pass the json and sort it like a normal array. It's fine